# Chaining promises to cope with asynchronous promise from a this.storage.get() call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, typescript

I am struggling to cope with handling asynchronous retrieval of data from local storage in my app, which is written in Angular2/ionic2.

The code I have is as follows:

```js
  request(args) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // Retrieve the token from the local storage, if available
    this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + value);
    });

    args = args || {};

    var url = this.API_URL + args.url;
    var method = args.method;
    var data = args.data || {};

    var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: this.use_session});

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      if (method == 'GET') {
        this.http.get(url, options)
          .map(res => res.text())
          .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
              resolve(data);
            },
            (err:any) => {
              data = {};
              data['status'] = 0;
              data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect to server. Please try again."];
              data['error'] = err;
              reject();
            },
            () => {
            }
          );
      }
    });
  }
```

The code that calls the request function looks like this:

```js
  authenticationStatus(){
    return this.request({
        'method': "GET",
        'url': "/user/"
      })
      .then((data:any) => {
          console.log('****** authenticationStatus: GET /user/ SUCCESS');
      });
  }
```

And this is in turn called like this:

```js
      this.djangoAuth.authenticationStatus()
        .then((data:any) => {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.enableMenu(true);
            this.root = PhotoPage;
          },
          (err:any)=>{
            this.loggedIn = false;
            this.enableMenu(false);
            this.root = LoginPage;
          });
```

I have difficulty wrapping my head around nested promises and cannot work out how to amend the code above so that the result of the `this.storage.get("token")` call has added data to the header before it is used in the code below. I think I need to chain the promises in some way but cannot work out exactly how.

Comment: native localStorage access is synchronous...not sure why yours is wrapped in a  promise

Comment: This is not native it is angularjs/ionic

Comment: which are both frameworks that use native javascript

Comment: Yes but their version of local storage uses promises and it is their version I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to chain two promises - it's actually easy. All you have to do is to return second promise from the callback that you pass to the first promise `then()` method.

You can rewrite your code like this (I moved the code that adds headers to separate function - I think it's more readable that way)

```
// returns a promise that resolves to headers
createHeaders() {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  // Retrieve the token from the local storage, if available
  return this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + value);
    return headers;
  });
}

request(args) {

  return this.createHeaders().then(headers => {
    args = args || {};

    var url = this.API_URL + args.url;
    var method = args.method;
    var data = args.data || {};

    var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: this.use_session});

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      if (method == 'GET') {
        this.http.get(url, options)
          .map(res => res.text())
          .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
              resolve(data);
            },
            (err:any) => {
              data = {};
              data['status'] = 0;
              data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect to server. Please try again."];
              data['error'] = err;
              reject();
            },
            () => {
            }
          );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The most difficult thing in all this is not to forget every and each necessary `return`.

Also, I noticed that your `Promise` will never complete if it receives any method other than `GET` - you might want to add `else` part with `reject`

```
if (method == 'GET') {
    ....
} else {
    reject(new Error('invalid method:' + method));
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with scoping of the args. The code falls over on the lines that use args.url and args.method.

Comment: I am using Typescript in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about `this`.  It's needed when calling createHeaders(), and it's needed inside the callback (that's why I changed `function` to `=>`). Fixed.